# two divs, one with scrollable elements and one fixed

Tags: html, css, telerik

So i have the right pane of a Telerik Splitter (don't worry the problem ain't about Telerik, this pane is purely HTML and Bootstrap based) inside a resizable window. The panel should look like a cart of complex objects. I'll try to give an example since i can't paste the code

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="cakes">
    <div class="nameOfCake"></div>
    <div class="row titles">
       <div class="col-md-2">Ingredient</div>
       <div class="col-md-2">Rarity</div>
       <div class="col-md-2">Cost</div>
    </div>
    //the rows below are generated dynamically and there can be an indefinite number of them
    <div class="row content">
       <div class="col-md-2">Sugar</div>
       <div class="col-md-2">Low</div>
       <div class="col-md-2">2 $</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row total">
    <div class="col-md-2">Total Cost</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">(number calculated dynamically with sum)</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Now, the problem is that i want *cakes* to be scrollable, and *total* to be not only fixed at the bottom of *container*, but also capable of following the bottom of the window if resized.

Think this as the panel when the window is maximized

[MAXIMIZED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2vrV.png)

and this as the panel when the window is resized to be smaller

[RESIZED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EZal.png)

*Total* remains always at the bottom of such panel no matter what, and when needed, a scrollbar should appear to let you see everything in the content.

The problem is, i can't manage to do both things.

Setting *Total* as **position: absolute** and **bottom: 0** makes it going above the content, obviously, and using flexboxes with **margin:auto** puts it at the bottom only when maximized. And i can't manage to generate the scrollbar either (for those that know Telerik, yes i've deactivated the "normal" scrollbar of the Splitter). I've tried using **overflow:auto** and **overflow:scroll** both with and without setting a **max-height** and/or **min-height** for *cakes*

P.S. sorry for the raw explanation, first post here

Comment: Is there some reason Total can’t be position fixed, since that seems to what you want it to do, stay fixed.

Comment: I've tried with both fixed and absolute, and i can't manage to generate the scrollbar for cakes specifically, and when i try to generate it outside cakes, like for example in container, it acts like absolute, hovering over everything. I don't know if fixed + a functioning scrollbar for cakes would work since i didn't manage to do that

Comment: So what is supposed to give `.container` its height, when there is little content?

Comment: there is no fixed height for .container. This panel is part of a window that gets maximized when opened, but it can be resized in any possible way. You could potentially set a max and min height based on how much size can cake occupy depending on his dynamic data (which i did try, but didnt work). For instance tho, i also tried to set a fixed height for container and/or cakes, didnt work. I even tried to wrap every cake in his own div and have the "titles" as a single div at the start. still didn't work

Comment: How is container styled? E.g.what is its position value?

Comment: I tried with position:relative for the most part